# Simple (but not for me) - Translate ActionScript 3 to C# code

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, code-translation

recently I have discovered C#, which is really what I want. Before C# I was coding with AS3. I've recoded all my old program using C# but I am blocked with this :

```
public function Envoie_Serveur(param1:String) : void
{
    var _loc_2:* = String(this.CMDTEC % 9000 + 1000).split("");
    this.Serveur.send(this.MDT[_loc_2[0]] + this.MDT[_loc_2[1]] + this.MDT[_loc_2[2]] + this.MDT[_loc_2[3]] + param1);
    var _loc_3:* = this;
    var _loc_4:* = this.CMDTEC + 1;
    _loc_3.CMDTEC = _loc_4;
    return;
}
```

`CMDTEC and MDT are 2 byteArray (byte[] in C# I guess)`

That is what I have **tried** but which is not working ;c

```
byte[] _loc_1 = Encode((Int64.Parse(this.CMDTEC[0].ToString("X", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)) % 9000 + 1000) + "");
var fingerprint = new byte[4];

fingerprint[0] = byte.Parse(this.MDT[_loc_1[0]].ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
fingerprint[1] = byte.Parse(this.MDT[_loc_1[1]].ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
fingerprint[2] = byte.Parse(this.MDT[_loc_1[2]].ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
fingerprint[3] = byte.Parse(this.MDT[_loc_1[3]].ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
this.CMDTEC++;
```

And for exemple, that is what CMDTEC and MDT contains :

```
this.MDT = "1400175151406"; (just for exemple, I get this by socket)
this.CMDTEC = "8306"; (idem as ^)
```

How can I convert properly that to C# please ? Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: For starters, what line are you getting an error and what exception is the compiler giving you?

Comment: From what that last chunk of code looks like, you are taking a byte array, putting it into a long (64-bit integer) and then breaking it back into a byte array. Is that what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: I really don't know how to translate that, so I've tested what I guess the most logic, but the number returned (byte *) was not good.

Comment: What about the error messages the compiler is giving you and where?

Comment: Compilator do not throw an error. But the bytes returned are not what I need :x

Comment: Since you are not getting any exceptions, I am thinking that you are using the wrong data. I did notice a mismatch between variable names between the provided code blocks, in the first, you have used `_loc_2` and in the second, you used `_loc_1`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Variable name is not important, I think I am building like a bullshit the bytearray :x